# How to find all fields with a trailing comment

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I use IntelliJ IDEA, which has a nifty feature called structural search.  I want to use it to find all fields in all classes that have a comment at the end, like this:

```
class Thing {
    double x; // arbitrary comment (any text goes here)
}
```

So far nothing I've tried seems to work.

Comment: maybe a regex would work better

Comment: [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html) looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: No, more like this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html

Comment: I seriously doubt I can pull this off robustly with a regex

Comment: Just do edit -> find -> find in path and use the string "// the x-coordinate" and it'll search all files and folders in your project. You may get some false-positives that aren't in the structure you want, but how many things are going to have that exact comment string?

Comment: It appears I was not clear.  I don't care about that exact string, I want to find ALL comments that appear in such a position.

Comment: So, maybe will be better finding occurances "; //" ?

Comment: Clever, but too many false positives I think.  I want this only for fields (member variables), not local variables or other statements.

Comment: *So far nothing Ive tried seems to work* is not helpful. When you have done specific things, then list them here - or why exactly do you think others should spent their time on trying the same things you tried?!

Comment: Good point, I should have done that; will do when I get back to that computer.

Comment: Actually, in retrospect, maybe it's good I didn't.  There would be a risk of someone trying to fix my fundamentally broken idea instead of thinking of one from scratch that works better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following structural search string:

```
@Modifier("Instance") $FieldType$ $Field$ = $Init$; // $Comment$
```

> - Set `Occurrences Count` to `1, 1` for all variables except `$Init$`,
>     to `0, 1` (optional).

If you want static fields as well:

```
$FieldType$ $Field$ = $Init$; // $Comment$
```

> - Set `Occurrences Count` to `1, 1` for all variables except `$Init$`,
>     to `0, 1` (optional).
> - Set `Field`'s `Script Constraint` to `Field instanceof com.intellij.psi.PsiField` (can be defined on `Complete Match` too, shouldn't matter).

Comment: I am going to try this!  Thanks.

Comment: Wait, come to think of it, I actually want static variables too, but not local ones.

Comment: Okay, wow, that's advanced.  I looked for info about psi stuff (not very hard) and failed to find much.  Thank you!!

Comment: @MarkVY To be fair I didn't find much documentation about it. I kinda found about it while looking into it (which was a fun challenge :) )

Comment: That's very brave of you